# can we send Facebook Notifications using app scoped user ids?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am struggling with one problem.

I have to send notification to Facebook Users. According to >=2.0 version of Graph API, we get app scoped ids of user instead of original UIDs.

My question is: *can we send notification to user using these new app scoped ids?*

As i tried to send notification with app scoped ids, code failed. But When I tried same code with original user id, it worked.

Please let me know if there is any way to solve this problem.

Thanks in Advance.

**Here is my code:**

```
require_once "/facebook_api/facebook.php";
$facebook = new Facebook();
$app_id = '<app_id>';
$app_secret = '<secret_id>';
$app_access_token = $app_id . '|' . $app_secret;
$id = '<app-scoped-id>'
$response = $facebook->api( '/'. $id .'/notifications', 'POST', array(
    'template' => 'You have received a new message.',
    'href' => 'http://test.com',
    'access_token' => $app_access_token
));

print_r($response);
die;
```

**RESPONSE:**

If is use app-scoped user id, response is:

```
PHP Warning:  Missing argument 1 for Facebook::__construct(), called in /facebook/message.php on line 4 and defined in /facebook/facebook_api/facebook.php on line 47

PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: config in /facebook_api/facebook.php on line 51

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught GraphMethodException: Unsupported post request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api
```

thrown in /facebook/facebook_api/base_facebook.php on line 1283

if i use original user id, result is: `Array(['success']=>1);`

Comment: it definitely works, i am doing this in many projects. but without any code and any error message, it´s impossible to help you.

Comment: @luschn i have updated my question. Please check.

Comment: Are you using v3 of the Facebook PHP SDK? If so, you need to pass a config array containing at least `appId` and `secret`.

Comment: @secret yes, i have tried that too. .

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can use both the global ID and app scoped ID in your app. Facebook seems to have relaxed this restriction.

If your app scoped ID isn't working, file a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing the same thing and it also works with real userID, but when I use app scoped id, I get this error :

```
(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: ...
```